# Elasticsearch filter by result of nested aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Say we have the following items index with nested reservations property. Each item has a quantity property where they can specify how many stocks they have.

It would be easy to create a query searching for keywords based on the item title and description, but I have no idea how to create a query to satisfy the following statement "I need to know who has available wheelchairs between Jan 1 to Jan 10."

First I check whether there's wheelchair in the title and description, then for each of those items, I need to sum all the reservations from Jan 1 - 10 then subtract it to the item's quantity to know that the item is available.

How does this translate to an elasticsearch query?

```html
PUT items
{
  "mappings": {
    "default": {
      "properties": {
        "owner": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "fullDescription": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "quantity": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "reservations": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "endDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "date_optional_time"
            },
            "quantity": {
              "type": "long"
            },
            "startDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "format": "date_optional_time"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use date histogram for aggregation and then use sum aggs in inner terms